# Regex - everything but anything within parenthesis

Tags: regex, expression, pcre

Having, let's say:

```
fieldA=20 and (fieldB=date() and (fieldC=35 and fieldD=40)) and fieldE = 100
```

I'm trying to replace outter "and" words, something:

```
fieldA=20 zzz (fieldB=date() and (fieldC=35 and fieldD=40)) zzz fieldE = 100
```

I've tried for hours, with no success. I could find some answers regarding how to get everything *inside* either parenthesis or brackets. The following expression is getting everything inside parenthesis, but I don't actually know how to write an expression that ignores just that:

```
\(([^()]*+|(?R))*\)    # retrieves "(fieldB=date() and (fieldC=35 and fieldD=40))"
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Don't think regex will work here. Better try iterating the string by hand and count opening/closing parens.

Comment: Is it PCRE regex flavor?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew please note that in my desired output, first and last "and" are replaced with "zzz"

Comment: A PCRE regex will work fine, e.g. [`(\(([^()]*+|(?1))*\))(*SKIP)(?!)|\band\b`](https://regex101.com/r/bF5eH4/1)

Comment: @tobias_k that's what I initially thought, but I feel I'm pretty close using Regex since I can get everything inside parenthesis...

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew that works like a charm! thanks! go on and write it down as an answer ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `\(([^()]*+|(?R))*\)` pattern contains a whole pattern recursion construct `(?R)` allowing to match nested parentheses and everything inside them. What you need is to omit everything matched with this subpattern and match `and` as whole words outside those. We need to put this whole subpattern into a capturing group and replace `(?R)` with `(?1)` to only recurse the first capturing group pattern, not  the whole pattern.

The `(*SKIP)(?!)` construct can be used to omit currently matched alternative in a PCRE regex.

Thus, use

```
(\(([^()]*+|(?1))*\))(*SKIP)(?!)|\band\b
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/bF5eH4/1)

In short,

- `(\(([^()]*+|(?1))*\))(*SKIP)(?!)` - match nested parentheses with everything inside, omit this matched text and go on analyzing the string
- `|` - or...
- `\band\b` - match and return the whole word `and`

Comment: Perfect explanation :-)
@Shafizadeh solution also works perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: His solution works only if you have 2 `and`s. If you have more, that solution won't work. Mine is generic for PCRE.

Answer (score 2):

Try this pattern:

```
/^(.*?)(?:and)(.*)(?:and)(.*)$/
```

And replace with:

```
$1 zzz $2 zzz $3
```

#### [Online Demo](https://regex101.com/r/rP5pD8/1)